# Automatic Highlighting Outliers in ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe df. While plotting this in ggplot. Can we also highlight outliers. Below is the sample code

```
df <- data.frame(col=runif(100, min=0, max=100000))
df$D <- c(1:100)
ggplot(df,aes(x=D,y=col))+geom_line()
```

Is there the way to highlight outliers here

Comment: How do you define an outlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define a function for this. The `line_outlier_plot` has four arguments. `df` has the same format as your example data frame. `outlier_color` and `normal_color` are to specify the color for the points.`drop` indicates if we want to drop the category in the legend.

We have to define how to determine an outlier. Here, I decided that an outlier is a value larger or smaller than the mean plus or minus 3 times of the standard deviation. You can define your own approach to determine the outlier by modifying the code in the `ifelse` statement.

```
library(ggplot2)

line_outlier_plot <- function(df, outlier_color = "red", normal_color = "black", drop = FALSE){
  # Assign a label to show if it is an outlier or not
  df$label <- ifelse(df$col > mean(df$col) + 3 * sd(df$col) |
                     df$col < mean(df$col) - 3 * sd(df$col), "Outlier", "Normal")

  df$label <- factor(df$label, levels = c("Normal", "Outlier"))

  # Set the color palette
  pal <- c("Outlier" = outlier_color, "Normal" = normal_color)

  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = D, y = col)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(color = label)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = pal, drop = drop)

  return(p)
}
```

Below is an example of the plot using this function.

```
set.seed(155)

df <- data.frame(col=rnorm(1000))
df$D <- c(1:1000)

line_outlier_plot(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, May i know what is ````scale_color_manual(values = pal, drop = drop)```` doing here?